# TCPDump - Filter by MAC Address

Tags: mac-address, ip, tcpdump

I would like to display all traffic for or from a specific MAC address.
For that I tried

```
sudo tcpdump host aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
```

It does not work and returns me an error

```
tcpdump: pktap_filter_packet: pcap_add_if_info(en0, 1) failed: pcap_add_if_info: pcap_compile_nopcap() failed
```

I don't know how to interpret this error message and I don't know how to solve the problem.

Any help ?

Comment: Are you sure it is the correct MAC address format? MAC addresses don't have a standard format. I have run into problems with different devices and code requiring different formats. Some need colons, some dashes, some with 2 digits, some with 3, some with 4, and, once, one that needed it cut into half.

Comment: Hi, yes pretty sure. This is the format used for responses when it works. Like for example this command works :
> sudo tcpdump -e -nni all ether src aa:bb:cc:11:22:33

EDIT : And it returns me approximately what I want basically. (I just discovered that)

Comment: That's a truly horrible error message, and tcpdump on OS X prior to Mavericks, or when not capturing on the "any" device on Mavericks and later, or on any *other* OS would report "tcpdump: ethernet address used in non-ether expression".  I've filed bug 21698116 on the Apple bug reporter for this.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You have used the following as your packet filter: `host aa:bb:cc:11:22:33`

As it stands, this is looking for an IP or hostname but you are giving it a MAC address.

To use a MAC address, you need to include the `ether` packet filter primitive.

In your case, the following should work:

```
sudo tcpdump ether host aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
```

Or, if it needs you to specify the interface, then it would be something like:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 ether host aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really well explained, I understand the "ether" parameter clearly now. One question now is why can not I see HTTP packet headers when I surf the web ? (I have an iPhone as a test device and I am sniffing for its MAC Address, if I ping it I can see the trafic, if I just wake it or make it sleep I can see the traffic, but nothing when surfing Safari)

Comment: No one could really say as we don't know your environment or where you are looking at the data in that environment. I would need to know a lot more before being able to answer that question.

Comment: Ok, I develop on a Mac running the last Os 10 Yosemite, and my test device is a iPhone 5S with iOs 7. The network is basic, one wifi access point, one mac, one iPhone.  The thing is, if I do a `sudo tcpdump` I will se all trafic on the network and if I surf the web on my Mac I will see lines like `11:54:20.887984 IP 10.11.204.50.56049 > 886entdc11.enterprise.886ventures.com.domain: 46247+ A? programmers.stackexchange.com. (47)`, but if I do a `sudo tcpdump host IPOfIphone` then I will not see anything from the internet trafic if I surf with the phone.

Comment: Assuming your "access point" is actually some sort of gateway device and provides your access to the Internet and that you are doing the tcpdump on the Mac: unless you have configured it to do so in some way, the iPhone's internet traffic doesn't go through the Mac so the Mac wouldn't see it.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, maybe I am missing the basis of networking (electrical background). So if I understand you are saying that I can only see traffic from/to my mac or broadcasted. But in that case, why can I see traffic when the phone is connecting to the wifi ? In that case I get a `11:45:52.852928 IP 10.11.204.15.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0*- [0q] 1/0/1 TXT "model=N51AP" (98)` which is a communication between the phone (10.11.204.15) and 224.0.0.251 which is definitely not my mac (I assume this is the access point).

Comment: Because that is multicast traffic and likely broadcast throughout your L2 network.

Comment: Got it, it makes sense. Thank you for your clear explanations.

Comment: I'm using `tcpdump -vvv -i eth1 ether host f0:27:2d:2d:b9:57 and arp` to sniff for ARP packets from my Amazon Dash button. It's working beautifully, but I'd like to just limit the capture to the src MAC. I'm close, but each filter I try isn't working. It's currently showing the ARP request and response to my router. I only want to show the request.

Comment: @user208145, you should only need to add the source primitive, so the section that changes looks like "ether src host" instead of what you have.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `not` argument in conjunction with YLearn's answer to filter out packets from a specific mac address. In my case I needed every packet except the ones from 00:11:22:33:44:55 and I used this-

`sudo tcpdump ether -i eth1 host not 00:11:22:33:44:55`